# Samsung working extremely slow

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, unrooting, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

I unrooted my tab then did a factory reset, I then rooted my tab with Kingo Root, after rooting was successful my tab's performance became very slow. So I decided to boot into recovery mode then wipe data and cache. After that I noticed that the Samsung logo is slow. After booting my tab's performance is extremely slow, it takes time to go to the settings. So I went to look at CPU usage then I saw 98% of my RAM is being used. But the're only a few process on the list using a bit of RAM but they keep restarting. So I removed the root of my tab to see if that works, but it didn't.
After rebooting my tab it says "process system isn't responding"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Reflash a stock rom and see if your problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Ya one click root apps can have funny side effects like that. since you can root i'd assume your bootloader is unlocked id suggest you use a program called odin on your pc and flash Chain fires auto root https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/
first do a hard reset deleting everything from the device. then flash the appropriate version on your device. i've used chainfire for a long time with no issues.

good luck